# Easy way to access webservices with GET queries?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to create a small Java client that can call a GET webservice with a query. Imagine a gas/fuel webservice like this:

```
http://mywebservice.com/search.xml?lat=50.5&lng=30.33&fuels=Diesel&radius=2
```

Ideally I'd have a website where the user can enter information like location, fuel, radius in km and so on.

What technology could I best use to make the webservice calls simpler?

At the moment I'm constructing the query manually like this:

```
stringbuilder.append("http://mywebservice.com/search.xml?lat=")
.append(latField.getText())
.append("&lng=")
.append(lngField.getText())
.append("&fuels=")
.append(fuelsField.getText())
.append("&radius=")
.append(radiusField.getText());
```

You get the idea.

I'm questioning: is there anything smarter to call webservice queries? How are you doing this? How could this be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up using `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient` as follows:

```
WebClient.create("http://mywebservice.com/search.xml")
    .query("lat", 50.5)
    .query("lng", 30.33)
    .query("fuels", "Diesel")
    .query("radius", 2)
    .get(Search.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAX-RS to build/deploy/invoke this REST endpoint easily.

The client may look like:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(".../gas");
MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
map.add("lat", "50.5");
map.add("lng", "30.33");
map.add("fuels", "Diesel");
map.add("radius", "2");
target.request().post(Entity.form(map));
```

A similar client code is at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples/blob/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/javaee7/jaxrs/client/TestJAXRS2Client.java

The endpoint may look like:

```
@Path("/gas")
public class GasService {

@POST
public String post(@FormParam("lat")String lat, @FormParam("lng")String lng) {
    // search based upon lat, lng, etc
}
}
```

A complete endpoint definition is at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples/blob/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/javaee7/jaxrs/client/MyResource.java

Answer (score 0):

A well known library is:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x
It is very simple and flexible.

```
For your usecase you could do something like:
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost("www.google.com")
        .setPath("/search")
        .setParameter("q", "httpclient")
        .setParameter("btnG", "Google Search")
        .setParameter("aq", "f")
        .setParameter("oq", "")
        .build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

For the full example and more:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e49

Answer (score 0):

I like spring a lot, so I could recommend you rest template :
http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

The example given is :

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("hotel", "42");
vars.put("booking", "21");
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}", String.class, vars);
```

To match your question, that could become :

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("lat", latField.getText());
vars.put("lng", lngField.getText());
vars.put("fuels", fuelsField.getText());
vars.put("radius", radiusField.getText());
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://mywebservice.com/search.xml?lat={lat}&lng={lng}&fuels={fuels}&radius={radius}", String.class, vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a webservice client using standard frameworks, depending on the type of webservice. For example, [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) for SOAP based or [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) for REST based.